# How to pass bearer token in a request apart from Authorization manager and Header manager

Tags: jmeter

I need to pass the token generated in one request into another request.

In second request,
I cannot pass the Authorization as the header because the API is not designed in a way to pass the token as header, nor Authorization manager is working as I need to pass the body and in Authorization manager I am not able to locate where to pass the body.

Is there any other way apart from Authorization manager or Header manager?

Answer (score 0):

- [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) generates and sends the relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header, the header value differs depending on the protocol which is being used for the authentication/authorization from [basic access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_control) to [NTLM and Kerberos](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)
- [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) allows you to send arbitrary [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) including the aforementioned `Authorization` one

Unfortunately we cannot suggest how exactly you can pass the token, you need to

- check the [API contract](https://lazaroibanez.com/development-what-is-an-api-contract-683ced58e06f?gi=ee3a9788dffd) or documentation, some [API implementations have special documentation endpoints](https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/)
- contact the people who "designed" the "API"
- capture the request from the real browser using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or if it's another application use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)